# Using R to merge columns with each entry into new row in large dataset

Tags: r

I have a text file that is formatted:

```
geneID1 A   C   C   C   C   C  
geneID2 T   T   T   T   T   T
```

There are 52, 749 rows of gene IDs and 152 columns of data, my text file does not have headers. I want to merge every two columns of data into a single column, alternating the data into each row to ultimately have 76 columns of data. So for example:

```
geneID1 A   C   C  
geneID1 C   C   C  
geneID2 T   T   T  
geneID2 T   T   T
```

I am able to merge columns together using the `paste0` command but this is not what I want as this just paste the two columns of data together as one. 
Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your file is a data.frame:

```
tab=read.table(text="geneID1 A   C   C   C   C   C  
geneID2 T   T   T   T   T   T",row.names=1)
```

We have to make everything a character using:

```
apply(tab,2,as.character)
```

And we can make this a vector row-wise, doing:

```
c(t(apply(tab,2,as.character)))
[1] "A" "C" "C" "C" "C" "C" "T" "T" "T" "T" "T" "T"
```

Now, we just need to put this back again by making it a matrix, with 1/2 the original number of columns

```
newdf = matrix(c(t(apply(tab,2,as.character))),ncol=ncol(tab)/2,byrow=TRUE)
newdf
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,] "A"  "C"  "C" 
[2,] "C"  "C"  "C" 
[3,] "T"  "T"  "T" 
[4,] "T"  "T"  "T"
```

And we give it a ID, because duplicate rownames are not allowed:

```
newdf= data.frame(
ID=rep(rownames(tab),each=2),
matrix(c(t(apply(tab,2,as.character))),ncol=ncol(tab)/2,byrow=TRUE)
)
newdf
       ID X1 X2 X3
1 geneID1  A  C  C
2 geneID1  C  C  C
3 geneID2  T  T  T
4 geneID2  T  T  T
```

Comment: The wording in the question is a bit vague, but I suspect `geneID` is a field in the raw file. If that is the case, we will want to be careful what we `apply` `as.character` to and what we pass as `ncol` inside of `matrix`. Unless I'm wrong and `geneID` are rownames in a dataframe.

Comment: True @ander2ed, I was thinking about that. I read in OP's post "There are 52, 749 rows of gene IDs and 152 columns of data", so I have to assume the geneID is rownames

Comment: That's fair. My assumption was based on the first line "I have a text file that is formatted:", implying OP had a raw tab separated text file with those contents. In any case, I like this solution.

Comment: Yes, sorry about the vague wording on that. In this case geneID is actually the rowname in the dataframe. I need to manipulate my data to get it into a completely different format than the original raw output from the program so it is a bit weird on how it is pieced together. But @StupidWolf this solution worked beautifully, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

hope this helps feel free to ask me anything.

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- tribble(~gene,~g11,~g12,~g13,~g21,~g22,~g23,
        "geneID1","A",   "C",   "C",   "C",   "C",   "C",
        "geneID2", "T",   "T",   "T",   "T",   "T",   "T")

df %>% 
  tidyr::unite("g1",g11:g13,sep = " ") %>% 
  tidyr::unite("g2",g21:g23,sep = " ") %>% 
  tidyr::pivot_longer(g1:g2) %>% 
  tidyr::separate(value,into = c("gene_p1","gene_p2","gene_p3")) %>% 
  select(-name)
```

Answer (score 0):

This question has been pretty thoroughly answered, but I'd like to offer a `data.table` solution that handles geneID as a field in your table, and retains an identifier of which position each value comes from. The advantage (I think) is that you can later `order`, subset, or re-`cast` to wide format.

```
library(data.table)
rm(list = ls())

dt <- data.table(
  geneID = c('geneID1', 'geneID2'),
  V1 = c('A', 'T'),
  V2 = c('C', 'T'),
  V3 = c('C', 'T'),
  V4 = c('C', 'T'),
  V5 = c('C', 'T'),
  V6 = c('C', 'T')
)

names <- paste(colnames(dt[, 2:ncol(dt)]),
               '_',
               seq(from = 2, to = ncol(dt), by = 1) %/% 2,
               sep = "")

colnames(dt) <- c("geneID", names)

> colnames(dt)
[1] "geneID" "V1_1"   "V2_1"   "V3_2"   "V4_2"   "V5_3"   "V6_3" 

patterns <- seq(from = 1, to = (ncol(dt) - 1) / 2, by = 1)

melt(
  dt,
  id.vars = "geneID",
  measure.vars = patterns(paste('_', patterns, sep = ""))
)[order(geneID, variable)]

    geneID variable value1 value2 value3
1: geneID1        1      A      C      C
2: geneID1        2      C      C      C
3: geneID2        1      T      T      T
4: geneID2        2      T      T      T
```

First, you will have to add column names to your data that follow some identifiable pattern. Since you want every two columns `melt`ed, you simply use integer division to divide the column indices by 2 and create new `colnames` by appending this value to the existing names and separating with some character, say `_`.

Next, you identify the patterns in the field names to `melt` by, and simply `melt` the data. Your data will still retain the `geneID` field, and now have a new column named `variable` which identifies the variable from each pair that was `melt`ed.